# "Node no longer exists" Yii

Tags: session, yii

I want to keep the data between 2 actions in Yii by session. i'm writing the data in one action

```
 Yii::app()->session['resultsData'] = $data;
```

and try to get it in next action

```
$this->resultsData = Yii::app()->session['resultsData'];
```

but when i want print_r this data in view...

```
<? print_r($this->resultsData); ?>
```

i'm get

```
PHP warning

print_r() [<a href='function.print-r'>function.print-r</a>]: Node no longer exists
```

actually, any manipulate with this data array, like serialize or json_encode, returns this error. can it be because of corrupted data? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii::app()->session['resultsData'];No need to use $this in action just assign the variable as shown

```
Yii::app()->session['resultsData'] = $data;
resultsData =Yii::app()->session['resultsData'];
```

and access it in another action as

```
echo  Yii::app()->session['resultsData'] ;
```

If U want to acces the resultData in another u need to pass that variable to that action as shown

```
$this->redirect(array('actionname','resultData'=>$resultData));
```

And in your actionname echo it or print_r and check

Send it to view as shown

```
$this->render('ViewName',array('resultData'=>resultData));
```

From view to action use this

```
Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('ControllerName/actionName',array('data'->$data));
```

Comment: i need to send data to the view. i tried even this
print_r(Yii::app()->session['resultsData']);

Comment: See updated post.And check wheather Yii::app()->session['resultsData'] is getting the value assigned of $data

Comment: but if i redirecting by javascript, what can you advice?

Comment: What are you redirecting by javascript ?? View or action

Comment: in view i redirect to the action like that
window.location.href = data.redirectUrl;

Comment: okay, one last question: in createAbsoluteUrl i can add a get parameter? like 'Controller/action/param'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you:

```
$model = new CompanyForm('step1');
        if (is_array(Yii::app()->session['step1']))
            $model->attributes = Yii::app()->session['step1'];

if (!is_array(Yii::app()->session['step1']))
            $this->redirect(array('createStep1'));

    $this->render('create', array(
        'model' => $model,
        'step' => 'step1'
    ));
```

maybe you are saving the data in the wrong place;

maybe you have a post or get action;

and also, print_r the $data and see wat you get before saving the data in session